# BIGQUERY DATETIME STRING Conversion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How do I convert a string like "17/12/2019 04:11:10 PM" to Output formats  like below

```
| INPUT                     | OUTPUT 1      | OUTPUT 2  |
|------------------------   |------------   |---------- |
| 17/12/2019 04:11:10 PM    | 2019-12-17    | 201912    |
```

Note: Output 2 can be a string

I have tried the

```
PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', LEFT(COMPLETED_DATE,10)) as COMPLETED_DATE,
PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', LEFT(COMPLETED_DATE,7)) as CALENDAR_MONTH,
```

Comment: When you convert a text date into a date, you get a date object conceptually, not another string.  Do you also want to _format_ your date a certain way here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
select 
  COMPLETED_DATE, 
  cast(parse_datetime('%d/%m/%Y %r', COMPLETED_DATE) as string format 'YYYYMM'),
  cast(parse_datetime('%d/%m/%Y %r', COMPLETED_DATE) as string format 'YYYY-MM-DD')
from table
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]